# Sanitizing inputs with AEM

Tags: aem, sanitization, html-sanitizing

We have various people updating our AEM website however when they copy and paste from word or from online it retains the HTML. I'm wondering if AEM has any built-in way of sanitizing the input so I don't need to build one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Rich Text Editor field in the dialog then the text will be parsed and some tags will be stripped. Take a look [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/wcm/using_rich_text_editor.html#Cut,%20Copy,%20Paste) for more information about how to configure it and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

We had a rich text edit component with same issue wherein authors were able to place HTML styling onto RTE and the placed styles were colliding with application styles and was breaking components. Fix was, we stripped out all HTML styling using jsoup API before rendering back on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach in AEM is to protect the user on output (i.e. take the input as-is and use the built-in XSS API when rendering that input).

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/security_checklist.html#Protect%20against%20Cross-Site%20Scripting%20%28XSS%29

https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/securitychecklist/_jcr_content/par/download/file.res/xss_cheat_sheet.pdf